gRPC reconnect with a new ip
I have a client and several servers, and the client initially randomly selects one server to use gRPC for communication. In order to prevent the server from suddenly hanging up (unable to recover), I hope that gRPC reconnection can allow the client to choose a new IP address (i.e. a different server). May I ask if there are any good solutions? Thank you～
I have learned that the built-in reconnection mechanism of gRPC is to connect to the same IP, but this does not solve my problem. I hope to solve the problem of connecting to another server after the server crashes. By the way, these servers have registered the same services.

Questions on Stack overflow should include code rather than be "How do I?". The documentation for gRPC Load Balancing isn't perfect. Load Balancing in gRPC is a good start. It covers the issue and a solution.
